# How to convert this google maps v2 API function to v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to convert this function to v3 API. This function is used to create an ellipse under a marker when selected. I have tried with projection and overlay, but without success.

```
  function makePolyPoints(_marker)
  {
    var polyPoints = Array();
    var markerPoint=  _marker.getLatLng();
    var projection = G_NORMAL_MAP.getProjection();
    var mapZoom = map.getZoom();
    var clickedPixel = projection.fromLatLngToPixel(markerPoint, mapZoom);
    var  ellipseRadA = 20;
    var ellipseRadB = 10;

    var polyNumSides = 20;
    var polySideLength = 18;

    for (var a = 0; a<(polyNumSides+1); a++) {
        var aRad = polySideLength*a*(Math.PI/180);
        var pixelX =  clickedPixel.x + ellipseRadA * Math.cos(aRad);
        var pixelY = -3 + clickedPixel.y + ellipseRadB * Math.sin(aRad);
        var polyPixel = new GPoint(pixelX,pixelY);
        var polyPoint = projection.fromPixelToLatLng(polyPixel,mapZoom);
        polyPoints.push(polyPoint);
    }
    return polyPoints;
}
```

Here the function for v3 that doesn't work, i think a problem of zoom level but I can't find how to replace projection.fromLatLngToPixel(markerPoint, mapZoom);

```
function makePolyPoints(_marker)
{
    var polyPoints = Array();
    var markerPoint=  _marker.getPosition();
    var projection = map.getProjection();
    var mapZoom = map.getZoom();
    var clickedPixel = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(markerPoint);

    var  ellipseRadA = 20;
    var ellipseRadB = 10;

    var polyNumSides = 20;
    var polySideLength = 18;

    for (var a = 0; a<(polyNumSides+1); a++) {
        var aRad = polySideLength*a*(Math.PI/180);
        var pixelX =  clickedPixel.x + ellipseRadA * Math.cos(aRad);
        var pixelY = -3 + clickedPixel.y + ellipseRadB * Math.sin(aRad);
        var polyPixel = new google.maps.Point(pixelX,pixelY);
        var polyPoint = projection.fromPointToLatLng(polyPixel);
        polyPoints.push(polyPoint);
    }
    return polyPoints;
}
```

Comment: What sort of result are you seeing from this?

Comment: in v2 it works perfectly, (example on this page http://www.allogarage.fr/main/carte.php?city=nice&Rechercher=Rechercher when you go over a marker on the map)

Comment: But what are you seeing in v3?

Comment: Nothing because doesn't exist anymore. I try to adapt the code, I can draw ellipse with projection but this doesn't take zoom level into account.

Comment: What exactly is the problem ? It's clear that you need to use the V3-equivalents of the used methods to convert it. As far as I see all the used method have an equivalent in V3, so use them.

Comment: I add some infos in the question. I don't find equivalent in V3 for fromLatLngToPixel and fromPixelToLatLng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm.. Im going to use one of my favorite gmap examples to help you out.

Using `var clickedPixel = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(markerPoint);` dont give you yet clickedPixel coordinates, they are still world coordinates. See [projection specs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Projection).

Specifying own mercator projection when calculating that kind of stuff is useful. Look closely to following lines: ([in this code example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates))

```
var worldCoordinate = projection.fromLatLngToPoint(chicago);
    var pixelCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(
    worldCoordinate.x * numTiles,
    worldCoordinate.y * numTiles);
```

(you can view source with firebug or similar).

If you dont have it (in mozilla: Tools -> web developer -> page source)

Hopefully, this will help you get through the problem :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I test your solution and it works perfectly, but finally I replace old code with a symbol : I calculate a SVG path for the ellipse, and then create a new marker on mouseover with a lower z-index.

Comment: Nice, care to vote up ? since seems to be solving initial problem of v2 to v3 method types? Helps community, thnx.

Comment: I can't until Iv' got 15 reputation sorry :(